# Weird texturing on background geometry

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, lighting

So I made a few dunes using the landscape addon and for some reason, the textures at a certain point just change colour.

[image]

I tried adjusting light paths, does nothing. Changing around the texture does nothing as well.

[image]

Any help at all would be much appreciated

[.blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lcMzd82AkKJYvpQo2e7t-6cxsn7UvLIy/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I am guessing it’s normals… possibly your normal texture being clipped. Disconnect it and see what happens.

Comment: Worked, thanks. No idea why I didn't try that

Answer (score 2):

You need to connect your Normal Map image texture through a *Normal Map* Node before connecting it to the Principled BSDF. Also, change the color space of your Normal Map image texture from *sRGB* to *Non-Color*:

[image: Normal]